# Convert a ResultSet to a String

Tags: java, type-conversion, resultset, jtextarea

I have a method that connects to and loads a database. It saves all of the usernames with scores into a ResultSet. At the moment, I can only get it to print separately to the console line by line. How could I save the whole ResultSet into a String so I can print this into a JTextField?

Model Class:

```
  public static void loadDatabase() {
    try {
        getDb().connectDB();
        getDb().createDB();
        ResultSet rs = getDb().getScores();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.print("Username: "+rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println(" Score: "+rs.getString(2));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();

    if (source == view.getSubmitButton()) {

    Model.getDb().insertScores(view.getUsernameTextField().getText(), Model.getScore()); //insert scores into table
    view.getInstructions().setText("Scores: ");
    }
}
```

getInstructions() is a JTextArea. I would like this line:

```
    view.getInstructions().setText("Scores: ");
```

to display the full list of scores

Comment: where do you call `loadDatabase()`?

Comment: `String usernameAndScore = rs.getString(1) + ": " + rs.getString(2);`? There are more sophisticated formatting possibilities but is this somewhat what you are looking for?

Comment: @DanielBarbarian he probably wants one single string, with ever user and its score

Comment: @Lino Probably and now there is an answer that covers that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a String in `loadDatabase()` with the text that you want:

```
public static String loadDatabase()
```

Inside, instead of printing to console, you just save those results to a String:

```
StringBuilder resultText = new StringBuilder();

while (rs.next()) {
    resultText.append("Username: ").append(rs.getString(1)).append(" Score: ").append(rs.getString(2));
}
return resultText.toString();
```

You would then need to call `loadDatabase()` before `view.getInstructions().setText("Scores: ");` and add it to that setText.

Comment: But you should really return a list of POJO to be more OO.

Comment: Good point, it would be better practice to return a List of some Object containing two Strings, username and score, and then creating a function that takes that List and parses everything into the desired String.

Comment: Using `+` inside the `append` method defeats the whole purpose of `StringBuilder`

Comment: @Lino You are right, I didn't even notice to edit that part, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing simpler than that. Use a StringBuilder to concatenate Your string while iterating:

```
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while( rs.next() ) {
    builder
        .append("Username: ").append( rs.getString(1) )
        .append( "Score: " ).append( rs.toString(2) )
    ;
}
String allResults = builder.toString();
```

But: Did you ask google before asking this question?

Comment: Uh. Alex GS was faster :)

Answer (score -2):

inside `loadDatabase()` :

Instead of

```
while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.print("Username: "+rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println(" Score: "+rs.getString(2));
        }
```

You should put:

```
String[] arrayofScores = null;
while (rs.next()) {
    String score= rs.getString(2);
    arrayofScores = score.split("\n");
    for (int i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arrayofScores [i]);
    }
}
```

Or you can use StringBuilder as @Alex GS suggested

Comment: This is not what OP wanted. He want's to display *all at once* on a gui

Comment: Why do you split `score` ? What do you think this is required ?